# judge if include the specified characters in a string vector?

Tags: r

```
strvec <- c("O.C[C@@](CC1=CC", "O[Al](O)OS",  "[Ca++]CC", "CCCCCCCCC=OOOO") 
inval.ele <- c("Al", "Ca", ".")
```

The string vector is `strvect`, and I would like to judge if the `strvec` include any element in the `inval.ele`. If include, it should be removed.

For above example, the final result should this:

```
"CCCCCCCCC=OOOO"
```

That means only this string is what I want.

In fact,  the length of `strvec` is more than 7000, and length of `inval.ele` is more than 20, what is the most efficiet way to deal with such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may also try `str_detect` in package `stringr`. The different strings in `pattern` can be separated by an "`|`" (`OR`). The "`.`" is a special character that needs to be escaped (see `?regex`), hence the "`\\`".

```
library(stringr)
strvec[!str_detect(string = strvec, pattern = c("Al|Ca|\\."))]
# [1] "CCCCCCCCC=OOOO"
```

Or using corresponding `base` function `grepl`

```
strvec[!grepl(x = strvec, pattern = c("Al|Ca|\\."))]
# [1] "CCCCCCCCC=OOOO"
```

A string of invalid elements may be created with `paste`:

```
inval.ele <- c("Al", "Ca", "Au", "Ag", "Xe")
inval1 <- paste0(inval.ele, collapse = "|")
inval1
# [1] "Al|Ca|Au|Ag|Xe"

# add the ".", which needs to be escaped
paste(inval, "\\.", sep = "|")
# [1] "Al|Ca|Au|Ag|Xe|\\."
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works and better  understanding.

Answer (score 1):

`grepl` will scan a vector for matches, but it will only take a single pattern.  To scan for multiple patterns, use a `for` loop.

In the code below, `rej` are matches to be rejected.  Default is to accept (reject is `FALSE`), and if any of the values match, the element in `rej` is set to `TRUE`.

Finally, use `!rej` to index `strvec`.

```
rej <- rep(FALSE, length(strvec))
for (p in inval.ele) { 
  rej <- rej | grepl(p, strvec, fixed=TRUE)
}
strvec[!rej]
## [1] "CCCCCCCCC=OOOO"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
strvec <- c("O.C[C@@](CC1=CC", "O[Al](O)OS",  "[Ca++]CC", "CCCCCCCCC=OOOO") 
inval.ele <- c("Al", "Ca", "[.]") #I've changed "." to "[.]" for gsub to recognize it

gsubfunc <- function(x, strvec){
  res <- strvec[gsub(x, "", strvec) != strvec]
}
setdiff(strvec, unique(unlist(lapply(inval.ele, gsubfunc, strvec))))
#"CCCCCCCCC=OOOO"
```

Comment: thanks David. But I test your solution using my whole dataset, and compare the result with those from Matthew and Henrik. it is different. Your solution give the length of solution of 6669 and both Matthew and Henrik give that of  6589. I will check if it is my reason.

Comment: here, your solution as: `res.3`

Comment: `strvec <- c(
"OC[C@H]1O[C@@H]([C@H](O)[C@@H]1OP(O)(=O)O[C@]([H])(C)CNC(=O)CC[C@]1(C)[C@@H](CC(=O)N)[C@@]2([H])N([Co]",
"O.C[C@@](CC1=CC(O)=C(O)C=C1)(NN)C(O)=O",
"[H]O[Co+]N1\\C2=C(C)/C3=N/C(=C\\C4=N\\C(=C(C)/C5=N[C@@](C)([C@@]1([H])[C@H](CC(=O)N)",
"O.[Gd+3].CNC(=O)CN(CCN(CCN(CC([O-])=O)CC(=O)NC)CC([O-])=O)CC([O-])=O",
"[Ca++].CC([O-])=O.CC([O-])=O")

inval.ele <- c( 
               "Co", "Gd", "Ca", "Dy", "Ho", "Er", "Tm", "Yb",
      "Ac", "Th", "Pa", "U", "Np", "Pu", "Am", "Cm", "Bk", "Cf", "Es", "Fm", "Md", "No", "[.]")` your solution seems like did not give the result.

Comment: This time, the result from you is 6479, and Matthew and Henrik is 6589 using my whole data set. Still different. I can not find the reason.

Comment: I wouldn't know if you wont provide the data, because on the examples you gave me it worked as good

Comment: Thanks David. There are many such strings like in the strvec, and more elements in the inval.ele. There are no other different. I do not know how the upload all these data. Anyway, it is good. I learn these methods.